# Why am I losing session when working with a dashed domain name (example-dashed.com)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I have a website which is www.abrisud.com. This website has 7 domain names (one for each language): abrisud.com, abrisud.it, abrisud.de, etc... and abrisud-enclosure.co.uk.

The problem is on the last one: I am losing my session on every single request. Each Time I load a page I have a different session ID. On the other domains everything is working just fine.

The website is running ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.0.

I am really convinced that the problem comes from the "-" in the domain name but I just can't find anything (or almost anything) on the subject through the web.

Hopefully I am being clear enough, if not just tell me.

Comment: Could there be a typo, with an underscore instead? `abrisud_enclosure.co.uk` would indeed drop cookies, as that's not a valid domain name; a dash (`-`) should generally work fine.

Comment: It seems I've had problems with some versions of IE and dashed domain names. Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: @Piskvor : It's not a typo, the domain name is abrisud-enclosure.co.uk, I know that the problem is known with underscore but I got it with dashes... :-(

Comment: @jeremy : I've tried so far on chrome 12 and firefox 4, and the problem is the same on both.

Comment: @Olivier de Robert: Thanks for the clarification, that is weird indeed. (oh, and is it an actual ASCII dash ( hex `0x2D` )? (the domain resolves, so probably yes; is it even possible to register a domain with em-dash?))

Comment: @Piskvor: Excellent question, thank you for asking it. I actually don't know, I never thought about that, let me figure this out that and I'll get back here to let you know.

Comment: @Piskvor: Yes the dash is an ASCII one, and I really don't h=think it's possible to register a domain name with a em(or en)-dash. For example if I try this www.abrisud—enclosure.com in my browser, it is interpreted as www.xn--abrisudenclosure-zg6i.com.

Any other ideas ? Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Are you specifying the session domain? If so, have you verified that your code for this is working as expected in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer :

From Module ActionDispatch::Http::URL (Rails 3.0.x), be sure to read the comments ;-)

```
# Returns the \domain part of a \host, such as "rubyonrails.org" in "www.rubyonrails.org". 
# You can specify a different <tt>tld_length</tt>, such as 2 to catch rubyonrails.co.uk in "www.rubyonrails.co.uk".
def domain(tld_length = 1)
  return nil unless named_host?(host)

  host.split('.').last(1 + tld_length).join('.')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, calling the *domain* method with the appropriate _tld_lenght_ argument did not play the trick, the request.domain (*abrisud-enclosure.co.uk*) was good, but not the session_domain (still *co.uk*).

So I had to add the following lines as a before filter to my application_controller :

```
def set_session_domain
  request.session_options[:domain] = request.domain
end
```

If you have a better solution I am open to it as I think this is a really dirty fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a peak at your site, the cookie is set with: domain=co.uk;path=/

So the problem is within your rails stack and not the browser(s) - time to do some debugging :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm looking into this right now and let you kown asap. So far I did not find the cookie set with domain=co.uk.